# Facebook Payment error code 1353009

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, payment

We are receiving from our users lots feedbacks about failed payments. In result we investigated that they get:

```
{ 
    "error_code": 1353009, 
    "error_message": "User is from a trade restricted country" 
}
```

But there are no restrictions in the settings of our application.
I have never found any information about this problem, maybe someone faced with it?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the user is detected as being in a US trade embargo'ed country; most likely Syria, Iran or Cuba (guess, based on those countries' sizes)

This wikipedia page gives an overview of the types of trade restrictions you could be encountering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargoes

Comment: Thank you for help! I hope that error codes page soon will be updated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/errorcodes/